# Searching database doesn't return duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, database

In c# i have program through which we can add a contact (name and phone number) to database and also search for a particular contact. But while searching the command doesn't return duplicate rows. Example: if there are two or multiple contacts with same name only one is returned. Why am I not seeing all the duplicates. Here is the code that I am using to search

```
using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(str))

{
 con1.Open();
 using (SqlCommand query1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ContactBook WHERE Name=@Name", con1))
     {
       query1.Parameters.Add("Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SearchbyName.Name;
       using (SqlDataReader dr = query1.ExecuteReader())
        {
          if (dr.Read())
          {
            Console.WriteLine(dr[0] + " " + dr[1]);
          }
          else
          {
          Console.WriteLine("No contact found with name {0}", SearchbyName.Name);
          }
       }
     } 
 }
```

Comment: No, you are reading only the first value.  If you want all of them, use a looping construct of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(dr.Read())` will only read one time and so you are only getting one time.
`dr.Read()` is used to read data from data reader.

```
using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(str))

{
 con1.Open();
 using (SqlCommand query1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ContactBook WHERE Name=@Name", con1))
     {
       query1.Parameters.Add("Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = SearchbyName.Name;
       using (SqlDataReader dr = query1.ExecuteReader())
        {
          while(dr.Read())
          {
            Console.WriteLine(dr[0] + " " + dr[1]);
          }
       }
     } 
 }
```